# Select the first element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginning with JavaScript and I have a following problem. My webpage by default shows content of all `<li>` that is Journal Articles, Working papers and Conferences. I would like to have selected the first `<li>` when I come to the website, that is in this case journal Articles.

[image]

Relevant part of the HTML code:

```html
<div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
  <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <ul id="portfolio-flters">
      <li data-filter=".filter-journal">Journal articles</li>
      <li data-filter=".filter-wp">Working papers</li>
      <li data-filter=".filter-conferences">Conferences</li>              
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
  
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-journal">
    Articles published in journals with IF.


  </div>
  

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-wp">
    
    <li>Misak, V. (2022). Crime and weather: Evidence from the Czech Republic (No. 9/2022). IES Working Paper.</li>
    <br>
    <li>Garcia-Bernardo, J., Jansky, P., & Misak, V. (2021). Common Agricultural Policy Beneficiaries: Evidence of Inequality from a New Data Set (No. 4/2021). IES Working Paper.</li>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-conferences">
  <u> 2022: </u>
    <li>Young Economists Meeting, Brno, Czech Republic</li>
    <li>MAER-Net Colloquium, Kyoto, Japan</li>

  
    
  </div>   
</div>
```

Javascript function:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let portfolioContainer = select('.portfolio-container');
  if (portfolioContainer) {
    let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(portfolioContainer, {
      itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
    });

    let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);

    on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
        el.classList.remove('filter-active');
      });
      this.classList.add('filter-active');

      portfolioIsotope.arrange({
        filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
      });
      portfolioIsotope.on('arrangeComplete', function() {
        AOS.refresh()
      });
    }, true);
  }

});
```

How can I modify my JavaScript function to select the first child of  by default, please?

Desired output is this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "select"?

Comment: @Pointy see desired output, please

Answer (score -1):

You code was a bit hard to work with because all the classes are missing and the indents didn't format properly in your question.

I wrote below a full example for how you can achieve the tabs effect your going for below. Hope it helps! I tried to keep it simple and add comments. LMK if you have any questions :)

```js
let currentTab = 0;
let tabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tabItem');
let tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('.tabContent');

function updateTabs() {
  // CYCLE THROUGH EACH tabItems
  for (let i = 0; i < tabItems.length; i++) {
    tabItems[i].className = i == currentTab ? 'tabItem tabItemSelected' : 'tabItem'; // SET TAB WITH INDEX currentTab TO INCLUDE tabItemSelected CLASS
    tabContents[i].style.display = i == currentTab ? 'block' : 'none'; // ONLY SHOW THE CONTENT THAT CORRESPONDS TO INDEX currentTab
  }
}

updateTabs(); // LOAD TO STATE 0 --> YOU CAN DO THIS IS document.onload for example

for (let i = 0; i < tabItems.length; i++) {
  let curI = i; // CACHE i LOCALLY
  tabItems[i].onclick = function() {
    currentTab = curI;
    updateTabs(); // UPDATE TABS ON CLICK...
  }
}
```

```css
.tabContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabItem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabItemSelected {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
  <div class="tabItem">TAB A</div><div class="tabItem">TAB B</div><div class="tabItem">TAB C</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="tabContent" style="color: red">
Content A
</div>

<div class="tabContent" style="color: blue">
Content B
</div>

<div class="tabContent" style="color: green">
Content C
</div>
```